# How to receive long data frame by esp32 rmt ringbuffer

Tags: c, esp32, infrared

I'm a newbie and I'm playing with ESP32 and IR receiver to capture signal from AC IR remote.
Currently, I refer to example code for capturing IR signal as follows:

```
static void nec_rx_init()
{
    rmt_config_t rmt_rx;
    rmt_rx.channel = RMT_RX_CHANNEL;
    rmt_rx.gpio_num = RMT_RX_GPIO_NUM;
    rmt_rx.clk_div = RMT_CLK_DIV;
    rmt_rx.mem_block_num = 1;
    rmt_rx.rmt_mode = RMT_MODE_RX;
    rmt_rx.rx_config.filter_en = true;
    rmt_rx.rx_config.filter_ticks_thresh = 100;
    rmt_rx.rx_config.idle_threshold = rmt_item32_tIMEOUT_US / 10 * (RMT_TICK_10_US);
    rmt_config(&rmt_rx);
    rmt_driver_install(rmt_rx.channel, 3000, 0);
}
```

```
//get RMT RX ringbuffer
RingbufHandle_t rb = NULL;
rmt_get_ringbuf_handle(RMT_RX_CHANNEL, &rb);

// rmt_rx_start(channel, rx_idx_rst) - Set true to reset memory index for receiver
rmt_rx_start(RMT_RX_CHANNEL, 1);

while(rb) {
    uint32_t rx_size = 0;
    //try to receive data from ringbuffer.
    //RMT driver will push all the data it receives to its ringbuffer.
    //We just need to parse the value and return the spaces of ringbuffer.
    rmt_item32_t* item = (rmt_item32_t*) xRingbufferReceive(rb, &rx_size, 1000);
...
}
```

Although IR signal is emitted from an AC IR remote is about 100 items but I always see that rx_size is only 256 (64 items). So it is problem, how can I capture total signals from AC IR remote?. Note that I set the buffer size from 3000 to 10000.

I appreciate any suggestion for me in order to deal with this problem.

Comment: `The last configuration step is installation of the driver in memory by calling rmt_driver_install(). If rx_buf_size parameter of this function is > 0, then a ring buffer for incoming data will be allocated. ` - what is your `rmt_driver_install` call?

Comment: @KamilCuk I've added my init function in the post

Comment: And did you check all the return values from all the functions so they don't fail? `rmt_driver_install` returns `esp_err_t` you should check if it's equal to `ESP_OK`.

Comment: I've already received only 64 instead 100 items as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue this past week. I was receiving a serial packet that was 128 bits, but only ever got the first 64. After digging into it a bit deeper I found that the hardware buffer on the RMT interface defaults to a 64x32-bit RAM block per channel. You can set the channel up to use the memory blocks normally assigned to subsequent channels if you need to receive more data at once.

For my project I used the following function to give 4 RAM blocks to channel 0, thus increasing the maximum receive size to 256 bits, which is more than enough for my application. I also had to move the receive to channel 4 since channel 0 was now using the memory block for channel 1.

`rmt_set_mem_block_num((rmt_channel_t) 0, 4);`

Documentation for this function can be found here:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/api-reference/peripherals/rmt.html#_CPPv421rmt_set_mem_block_num13rmt_channel_t7uint8_t

It's also worth noting that it did throw an error in the serial monitor while the issue was occurring, which did help find the cause of the issue.

```
E (33323) rmt: RMT[0] ERR
E (33323) rmt: status: 0x14000100
E (33373) rmt: RMT RX BUFFER FULL
```

With the default amount of RAM I was getting an error code of `0x14000040`, and when I increased it to 2 blocks I got a status code of `0x13000040`. After increasing to 4 blocks of RAM the error message stopped appearing.

Comment: This solution works for me. Your reference links are so helpful